# Ionic2 setRoot failing without error

Tags: ionic2

I have two root pages. And I am trying to switch between them using `setRoot`. The issue:

- 1->2 OK
- 2->1 OK
- 1->2 OK
- 2->1 nothing

And nothing means that the code row before is executed and the code row after it is also executed, and there is nothing in the console. The same in browser and on device.

I hoped it is a beta bug, thus I have made simple app with only this functionality to demonstrate the issue, but "unfortunately" that works.

What can `setRoot` prevent from working?

My environment is:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.24
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.14
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v5.4.0
```

*[Update 1 - 2016.04.15]*

See my code here: [on GIT](https://github.com/zorgoz/fireabase-auth-test). Note: should be something related to RX or Firebase. Setting root page back and forth works as long as I don't uncomment what's commented in the initial commit you see in "login.ts" and "profile.ts".

Thank you in advance for the suggestions

Comment: Could you share with us the code you have written to accomplish this bro.? Coz, we don't actually what you have written and what's causing the issue. I have used nav.setRoot before in one of my apps and it has worked fine then.

Comment: I have created a repo for it. See update.